# SVN merge not working

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

Following instructions on the svnbook website, I am attempting to get trunk changes into my branch, using the following command:

```
cd <working directory to merge to>
svn merge ^/<project-directory>/trunk
```

and it does not seem to work, as many trunk changes do not end up in the branch.

I've tried it both from the **command-line** and from **TortoiseSVN**, to no avail. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: No idea of how you attempted to do it in TortoiseSVN but there's a *SVN Merge* context menu that leads to a dialogue with fields like "URL to merge from" and "Revision range to merge", together with a "Show log" button to inspect the exact revisions. (I presume you are not using a SVN version from several years ago, before merge tracking was implemented.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález merge tracking was implemented in SVN 1.5 from year ~2008. I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I tried the context menu, with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little concerned that you have `project-directory` for your trunk's source in that example.

It should be `svn merge svn+ssh://url/of/repository/trunk .` if you're within a working copy of the branch to which you're merging. The source cannot be a working copy, but the target should be.

If it's a local repository you could use `file://` instead of `svn+ssh` as well, omitting the domain name from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, the question and the issue is not really related to TortoiseSVN. It's about [`svn.exe` command-line client that you use to run `svn merge` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html). Please, read [SVNBook | `svn merge` reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html) carefully because the command that you run is missing necessary arguments.

Right now, I see two problems with the command line:

- You use [caret notation `^` to address the repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#idm675), but on Windows computers, you must add two caret symbols instead of just one:

  > Windows users should not forget that a caret is an escape character
  >   on their platform. Therefore, use a double caret ^^ if you run the
  >   Subversion client on a Windows machine.
- The command line is missing merge target path. You should specify the path to the working copy where to run the merge operation.

I hope that this example will help:

```
svn merge ^^/<project-directory>/trunk .
```

Note the dot character. It instructs to merge into the current directory. Replace dot with path to the working copy if necessary.

Comment: It's better just to use double quotes. For example:  svn merge "^/<project-directory>/trunk" .

Comment: Yes, I do usually add 2 carets; I just showed 1 caret in the question because that is how it is shown in svn-book..

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that if I navigate to the working copy, then there is no need to specify it in the merge. I guess that must be my mistake; next time I need to do a merge I will try it; if it works I can accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get all changes on trunk you should do

```
svn merge -rLastRevisionMergedFromTrunkToBranch:HEAD url/of/trunk path/to/branch/wc
```

Source: [Merge trunk to branch in Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399669/merge-trunk-to-branch-in-subversion)

Comment: This is not answer, but just a copy-paste of another answer made to irrelevant question.